# how to show success message after sending email using sweet js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert

I'm trying to send email without reloading page . But after sending it should show success message using sweet js . Unfortunately it doesn't work .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#contact-form').on('submit',function(e) {  
  $.ajax({
      url:'mailer.php', //===PHP file name====
      data:$(this).serialize(),
      type:'POST',
      success:function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //Success Message 
     swal("¡Success!", "Message sent!", "success");
      },
      error:function(data) {
        //Error Message 
     swal("Oops...", "Something went wrong :(", "error");
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); 
  });
});
```

Comment: ohh i missed that...

Comment: My problem is showing message after sending .

Comment: use complete: function(){
     // Handle the complete event
   }

Comment: what do you mean ? could you write whole code please ?

Answer (score -1):

you can return something so you can know if the mail was sent or not,

by comparing the data

so you can do the following in the success part of the ajax:

```
success:function(data) {
if(data == 'something that you will know if it sent'){
    swal("¡Success!", "Message sent!", "success");
      },

}
```

also make sure that you put the scr of the sweet alert in the head.